# XML resource id not found

Tags: android, xml, layout

So, i have `xml` layout, and i get no errors, and even the `graphical preview` view shows how the layout looks, but when i call the activity that uses this layout, i get some error, that i do not know how to handle....

Here is the xml:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rlTopNumara"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="16dp" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvNamePickNumara"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                android:text="@string/lottery_ticket_application"
                android:textSize="32sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivHomePickNumara"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:paddingRight="16dp"
                android:src="@drawable/home" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rlOnNumara1DateTop"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/rlTopNumara"
            android:padding="16dp" >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivOnNumara1DateTop"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:padding="8dp"
                android:src="@drawable/on_numara" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvRandomIdOnNumara1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ivOnNumara1DateTop"
                android:text="@string/draw_date_" />

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/spinnerOnNumara1Numbers"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/ivOnNumara1DateTop"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/tvRandomIdOnNumara1" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/tlContentOnNumara1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/rlOnNumara1DateTop"
            android:stretchColumns="1" >

            <TableRow android:weightSum="7" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:padding="3dip"
                    android:text="@string/a" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/etonnumaraA1"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:maxLength="2" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/etonnumaraA2"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:maxLength="2" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/etonnumaraA3"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:maxLength="2" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/etonnumaraA4"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:maxLength="2" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/etonnumaraA5"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:maxLength="2" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/etonnumaraA6"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:maxLength="2" />
                </TableRow>
            <TableRow android:weightSum="4">
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/etonnumaraA7"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:maxLength="2" />
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/etonnumaraA8"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:maxLength="2" />
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/etonnumaraA9"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:maxLength="2" />
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/etonnumaraA10"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:maxLength="2" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow android:weightSum="7" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:padding="3dip"
                    android:text="@string/b" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/etonnumaraB1"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:maxLength="2" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/etonnumaraB2"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:maxLength="2" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/etonnumaraB3"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:maxLength="2" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/etonnumaraB4"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:maxLength="2" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/etonnumaraB5"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:maxLength="2" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/etonnumaraB6"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:maxLength="2" />
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow android:weightSum="4">
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/etonnumaraB7"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:maxLength="2" />
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/etonnumaraB8"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:maxLength="2" />
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/etonnumaraB9"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:maxLength="2" />
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/etonnumaraB10"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:maxLength="2" />

            </TableRow>

            <TableRow android:weightSum="7" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:padding="3dip"
                    android:text="@string/c" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/etonnumaraC1"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:maxLength="2" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/etonnumaraC2"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:maxLength="2" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/etonnumaraC3"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:maxLength="2" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/etonnumaraC4"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:maxLength="2" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/etonnumaraC5"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:maxLength="2" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/etonnumaraC6"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:maxLength="2" />
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow android:weightSum="4">
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/etonnumaraC7"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:maxLength="2" />
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/etonnumaraC8"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:maxLength="2" />
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/etonnumaraC9"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:maxLength="2" />
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/etonnumaraC10"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:maxLength="2" />
            </TableRow>

            <TableRow android:weightSum="7" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:padding="3dip"
                    android:text="@string/d" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/etonnumaraD1"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:maxLength="2" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/etonnumaraD2"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:maxLength="2" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/etonnumaraD3"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:maxLength="2" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/etonnumaraD4"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:maxLength="2" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/etonnumaraD5"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:maxLength="2" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/etonnumaraD6"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:maxLength="2" />
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow android:weightSum="4">
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/etonnumaraD7"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:maxLength="2" />
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/etonnumaraD8"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:maxLength="2" />
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/etonnumaraD9"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:maxLength="2" />
                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/etonnumaraD10"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:maxLength="2" />

            </TableRow>

            <TableRow android:weightSum="7" >

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:padding="3dip"
                    android:text="@string/e" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/etonnumaraE1"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:maxLength="2" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/etonnumaraE2"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:maxLength="2" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/etonnumaraE3"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:maxLength="2" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/etonnumaraE4"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:maxLength="2" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/etonnumaraE5"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:maxLength="2" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/etonnumaraE6"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:maxLength="2" />
            </TableRow>
            <TableRow android:weightSum="4">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/etonnumaraE7"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:maxLength="2" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/etonnumaraE8"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:maxLength="2" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/etonnumaraE9"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:maxLength="2" />

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/etonnumaraE10"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:inputType="number"
                    android:maxLength="2" />
            </TableRow>
        </TableLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/tlContentOnNumara1"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:paddingTop="16dp" >

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnCancelOnNumara1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                android:text="@string/cancel" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnDoneOnNumara1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/btnCancelOnNumara1"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                android:text="@string/done" />
        </RelativeLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

And here is the LogCat output:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{gokerakinci.lottery/gokerakinci.activity.onnumara.OnNumaraPickerActivity}: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f03001a
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2596)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2653)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:156)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1355)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5872)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:674)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f03001a
        at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1134)
        at android.content.res.Resources.loadXmlResourceParser(Resources.java:2359)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getLayout(Resources.java:950)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:395)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:375)
        at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1997)
        at gokerakinci.activity.onnumara.OnNumaraPickerActivity.onCreate(OnNumaraPickerActivity.java:58)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5312)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1111)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2552)at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2653) at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:156) at ...
```

Now i tried clean & rebuild and other stuff, but it doesn't work. Can anyone notice the problem here?

Comment: It's not relevant, it doesn't even execute, crashes on setContentView(); you can see that from the logcat.

Comment: the layout is too huge. Try getting rid of components, to isolate the issue

Comment: I will try to redo the whole thing, it's easier that way. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: May be because you forgot to close your `ScrollView`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that, actually, i had a problem with the image that i was referencing. Something was wrong with it, and it crashed the whole application.

Answer (score 5):

Your error lies in every occurence of `@id` instead of `@+id`

**EDIT**

You can't use `@id` unless you've explicitly defined an `id` in a resource file like

```
<resources>
    <item name="your_id" type="id"/>
</resources>
```

then you can use `@id/your_id` in your layout.

If you didn't do the above you must use `@+id/your_id`

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit? To my knowledge, difference is `@+id` is when you assign and id, and `@id` is when you reference it. I only used `@id` when i used it with statements like `below `... And i have other layouts that work this way, with no problems...

Comment: Sorry, i have tried your answer, and it doesn't work. Same error message.

Comment: what exactly did you try?

Answer (score 0):

Check your layout files must be set as AndroidResource.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is so late, but it may help someone else.

When you create a new Android Layout file, VS will automatically set the `Build Action` to `AndroidResource`. However, if you take a look at that file's properties, you will see a `Custom Tool` as an additional option, which is set to `MSBuild:UpdateGeneratedFiles`. As the name tells, it foreces the MSBuild to updated the generated resources which actually adds the new resource values. So, make sure your `Custom Tool` option is set to `MSBuild:UpdateGeneratedFiles`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to have (id with plus)

```
android:id="@+id/user_derogation_progress_bar"
```

not

```
android:id="@id/user_derogation_progress_bar"
```